# difference between User.username and username?

Tags: cakephp

In cakephp 2 , whats the difference between:

```
echo $this->Form->input('User.username');
```

and

```
echo $this->Form->input('username');
```

??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

depends on your form

if you use `this->Form->create('User')` there is no difference because it belongs to the same model
but if you save related data then you need to use the descriptive version to tell cake which model the field belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

The first explicitly defines the User model's username field, while the second falls back to the controller's default model, what is User if you are in your UserController but if your controller is e.g. PostsController your Post model should have a username field also to e.g. save the form data.